# “… prime numbers p for which $(p)^2$ divides $(p)_3$” — What does $(p)_3$ mean here?

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm looking at a page at PrimeCurios for the number 9999999900000001, at https://t5k.org/curios/page.php. (Search for that number where it says "Search Curios!") It makes several claims, including this one:

*9999999900000001 is the 8th known prime, p, such that $(p)^2$ divides $(p)_3$. Can you find other cases like this?*

I have no idea what $(p)_3$ means here. Can somebody define or explain this?

Comment: What do you tthink $(p)^2$ means? Seems they wouldn't use parrenthese if they just wanted the square, $p^2.$

Comment: Well, just a guess mind you, but if we say that $(p)^2$ means $p^2$ and that $(n)_m$ means "$n$ concactenated with itself $m$ times" then the claim is true.  I mean $p^2$ does divide $p$ concactenated with itself $3$ times.  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=999999990000000199999999000000019999999900000001mod+9999999900000001%5E2)

Comment: But, honestly, if they are going to use non-standard notation, they ought to have a convenient glossary.

Comment: But it looks like tthere is no real way to tell what the submitter Green meant by this. Any answer would be a guess.

Comment: @lulu That was a good guess. You're probably right. I've certainly never seen that notation before, but that kind of thing comes up with prime curios a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what the first $7$ primes might be.  $3^2\,|\,333$ would be the first one.  And I think $13^2\,|\,131313$ is the second. Haven't searched for others.  Hard to believe your $p$ is only the $8^{th}$ such.

Comment: The OEIS has a [list](https://oeis.org/A147554)

Comment: @PrincessEev  Ha!  Thanks for that link.  I am really surprised that this $p$ is only the $8^{th}$ but here we are.

Comment: @lulu You might want to answer this question instead of just commenting. That way I can close the question.

Comment: @PrincessEev Thanks for that link. It has four members of the family of numbers I'm studying! The first from that list is 9901.

Comment: I'm most interested by the statement at the bottom of the curios list: $$9999999900000001 = 99999999^2 + 99999999^1 + 99999999^0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The (somewhat unusual) notation means that $p^2$ divides the concatenation of $p$ with itself three times.  For instance, $13$ passes the test since $13^2$ divides $131313$.

As confirmation, we have this OEIS list [A147554](https://oeis.org/A147554) supplied by user @PrincessEev